# SQL Server : performing arithmetic operations on values returned through query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am a SQL noob so looking for some help here. I have an example query like given below. Now I would like to modify the query so that I can perform the following operation on the Test, Test1 and Test2 values in the same query:

```
OutputValue = Test + Test1 - Test2
```

Then show the result of OutputValue along with Test, Test1 & Test2.

```
SELECT
    CAST(balancefwd.Shares AS NUMERIC) / 1000 AS Test, 
    SUM(CAST(booksdata.sharesissued AS NUMERIC) / 1000) AS Test1, 
    SUM(CAST(booksdata.sharesretired AS NUMERIC) / 1000) AS Test2
FROM
    SQLTest.TestBooks.dbo.booksdata booksdata
JOIN
    SQLTest.TestBooks.dbo.balancefwd balancefwd ON booksdata.companynumber = balancefwd.companynumber
WHERE
    booksdata.CompanyNumber= '<number>' 
GROUP BY 
    balancefwd.shares
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: mysql or sql server 2008 reading dbo in your query looks like you are using sql-server 2008. please correct the tags by editing your question.

Comment: Changed the tags. Test is a static value for a company and i have added the group by clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer to the problem:
  Giving a name to the sub query(t1) I was able to perform arithmetic operations on the derived values.

```
Select t1.Test, t1.Test1, t1.Test2, t1.Test+t1.Test1-t1.Test2  as OutputValue from
(SELECT
     CAST(balancefwd.Shares AS NUMERIC) / 1000 AS Test, 
     SUM(CAST(booksdata.sharesissued AS NUMERIC) / 1000) AS Test1, 
     SUM(CAST(booksdata.sharesretired AS NUMERIC) / 1000) AS Test2
 FROM
     SQLTest.TestBooks.dbo.booksdata booksdata
 JOIN
     SQLTest.TestBooks.dbo.balancefwd balancefwd ON booksdata.companynumber = balancefwd.companynumber
 WHERE
     booksdata.CompanyNumber= '<number>' 
 GROUP BY 
     balancefwd.shares) t1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your query in another layer :

```
SELECT t.*, t.test + t.test1 - t.test2 as total
FROM (Select cast(balancefwd.Shares as numeric)/1000 as  Test, 
             sum(cast(booksdata.sharesissued as numeric)/1000)as  Test1,
             sum(cast(booksdata.sharesretired as numeric)/1000)as  Test2
      from SQLTest.TestBooks.dbo.booksdata booksdata
      join SQLTest.TestBooks.dbo.balancefwd balancefwd on booksdata.companynumber=balancefwd.companynumber
      where booksdata.CompanyNumber= '<number>')
```

Then the derived columns will be available for use.

Though your query looks a bit wrong.. what are you trying to do here? Why no group by clause? Is there only 1 record in the table? Why do you sum `test1` and `test2` but not `test` ?